# Using TOBAG and STRSPLIT in Pig Latin

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, apache-pig

I have a file with the following contents

```
1,2,3|4,5,6
```

The first seperator is '|' and the next seperator is ','.

I want my output to be present in the following format

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Do you know any pig latin script available for this.

Thanks,

Regards,
Dheeraj Rampally.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind.I got the answer.

```
A = load 'abc.txt';
B = foreach A generate FLATTEN(STRSPLIT($0,'\\|'));
C = foreach B generate FLATTEN(TOBAG(*));
store C into 'def';

A1 = load 'def';    
B1 = foreach A1 generate FLATTEN(STRSPLIT($0,'\\,'));    
C1 = foreach B1 generate FLATTEN(TOBAG(*));   
store C1 into 'ghi';
```

gave me the solution.

Thanks,

Regards,
Dheeraj Rampally.